# How to change Vector to Array or ArrayList?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn  ArrayList and Vector.
If for example I have `private Vector cardsInMyHand;` can I change it to ArrayList. As you see or I am wrong.

```
    private Vector numbers;
    .
    .
    .
    Vector studentNumbers;
    studentNumbers = new Vector();
    public int getNumbers(Vector studentNumbers, int x)
    {

       if (x >= 0 && x < studentNumber.size())
       {
          return ((Integer)hand.elementAt(x)).intValue();
       } else
         {
            return 0;
         }
   }
```

change to private ??????; ...... `ArrayList<String> studentNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();`
Can I do this ?

```
   public int getNumbers(ArrayList studentNumbers, int x)
   {

     if (x >= 0 && x < studentNumber.size())
     {
        return ((Integer)hand.elementAt(x)).intValue();
     } else
       {
        return 0;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Vector is a Collection so you can just do numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]) to convert the Vector<String> to a String[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but your syntax has a few typos. And you should not use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Finally, I suggest you use the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and read about [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

```
public int getNumbers(List<Integer> studentNumbers, int x) {
    if (x >= 0 && x < studentNumbers.size()) {
        return studentNumbers.get(x);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand about raw typesBox<String> stringBox = new Box<>();
Box rawBox = stringBox;

Comment: you mean this is a raw type ArrayList<String> studentNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @JayLo When you say just `ArrayList objs;` it is a raw type (it behaves like `ArrayList<Object> objs;`). The diamond operator on the right is short-hand, `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();` for `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the below example with type safety.

```js
public ArrayList<String> convertVectorToList(Vector<String> studentNoVec){
     return new ArrayList<String>(studentNoVec); 
  }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Vector<String> v= new Vector<String>();
  v.add("No1");
  v.add("No2");
  Test a = new Test();
  for(String no : a.convertVectorToList(v)){
   System.out.println(no);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated. If you want to convert Vector to an ArrayList use the below mentioned way. Simple and easy.

```html
// convert vector to araryList  
public ArrayList convertVectorToList(Vector studentNoVec){
   return new ArrayList(studentNoVec); 
}
```

Comment: **Please** do not use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: Yes! Its an example. Any Type can be used for Vector and ArrayList.